# Changin Navigation Drawer Icons in Android

Tags: android, vector, icons, navigation-drawer

I created an activity as with the navigation drawer property in android. I want to change the icons to some images that I created before, but do not know how to do that, I tried changing the icon info from the XML below but it is not working with png, jpg or ico files.

The below part is in the activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Search/Add People" />
```

When I click to the icon (ic_menu_send) it takes me to the xml below:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M2.01,21L23,12 2.01,3 2,10l15,2 -15,2z" />
</vector>
```

How can I use another image? Any help would be great!

[image: Navigation Drawer Image Part]

Answer (score 0):

Put the icon you want to show in drawable folder lets say name is "icon_send.png" and use it as  follows :

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_send"
        android:title="Search/Add People" />
```

Comment: Thank you Krishna, I guess I found the problem, when I try to save the image to drawable, the system asks if I want to save to drawable or drawable(v21), when I choose drawable, the image can not be used in the navigation drawer, but in the other it can be used.